# Get List of Facebook IDs that liked a Page to text file

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the entire list of Facebook IDs (the ID field from Graph API) from people that have liked my community page(I am admin).

I would just simply like to put this into a text file, preferably just delimited by commas.

What would be the most efficient way to do this? Can this even be done?

Comment: You can not fetch the IDs of the people who have liked your page!

Comment: The current API doesn't allow that